# Analysis of a general equation

Tags: analysis, functions

Consider the function

$\phi(x) = a(x)+b(x)$,

with $x\in\mathbb  R$.

Assume for some $y=x$ it holds $\phi(y)=0$.

Furthermore, assume $a$ and $b$ are bounded for all $y$.

Let the function values $z_1 = a(y)$ and $z_2 = b(y)$. Then, either $z_1=-z_2 \ne 0$ at $y$ or $z_1= z_2 = 0$ at $y$.

Without knowing $a(x)$ and $b(x)$, is it possible to say something about the properties they must have when for all $y$ where $\phi(y)= 0$ also $z_1  = 0$ and $z_2 = 0$ and not $z_1 = -z_2 \ne 0$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it is not clear. As I wrote (first) in the title, I refer to different function values, as e.g. in your example both graphs are 0 at x= 0. I tried to correct the quesion to make it clear.